# How to save data recieved from tcp/ip server into textfile in java

Tags: java, sockets, networking, tcpclient

I have written a small program in Socket Network in java which is communicating to server using IP address and port number. Now the data from the server will be received continuously. I want all this data received from server to be stored in a text file but have no idea how to do it without the application hanging.

Here is my code:

```
public class Client
{

    public Client()
    {
        try
        {
            //ceating the socket to connect tso server running on same machine binded on port no 3000
            Socket client=new Socket("localhost",3000);
            System.out.println("Client connected ");
            //getting the o/p stream of that connection
            PrintStream out=new PrintStream(client.getOutputStream());
            //sending the message to server
            out.print("Hello from client\n");
            out.flush();
            //reading the response using input stream
            BufferedReader in= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
            System.out.println(in.readLine());
            //closing the streams
            in.close();
            out.close();

        }
        catch(Exception err)
        {
            System.err.println("* err"+err);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String a[])
    {
        new Client();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a tested code.Try this one.

```
  StringBuffer instr = new StringBuffer();

  /** Establish a socket connetion with the server*/
  Socket connection = new Socket(address, port);

  /** Instantiate a BufferedOutputStream object */
  BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());

  /** Instantiate an OutputStreamWriter object with the optional character
   * encoding. Sending some message to server
   */
  OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(bos, "US-ASCII"); 
  String process = "SAMPLE COMMAND SENT TO SERVER"+(char)13;

  /** Write across the socket connection and flush the buffer */
  osw.write(process);
  osw.flush();

  // NOW READING THE RESPONSE FROM THE SERVER
  // I HAVE ADDED THE CHAR(13) as the delimiter here
  /** Instantiate a BufferedInputStream object for reading
  /** Instantiate a BufferedInputStream object for reading
   * incoming socket streams.
   */

  BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
  /**Instantiate an InputStreamReader with the optional
   * character encoding.
   */

  InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(bis, "US-ASCII");

  /**Read the socket's InputStream and append to a StringBuffer */
  int c;
  while((c=isr.read())!=13)
    instr.append((char)c);

  /** Close the socket connection. */
  connection.close();
```

Comment: Thank you Sir for your response as i am very new in socket programming will you please guide me how can i save the live stringbuffer data into textfile

Comment: Its rather very easy, learn from this site about file writing: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-write-to-file-in-java-bufferedwriter-example/